# Saving rasters to postgresQL using raster2pgsql, saving forecast time

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I would like to save a forecast which is saved as geoTiffs into a postgresQL database. I've been able to import the rasters using:

raster2pgsql -s 0 -I -d tiff/field*.tiff -F public.latest | psql -d optigrid

THis gives me a table latest which looks like

```
rid  | rast  | filename
1      ...     field1.tiff
2      ...     field10.tiff
```

and so forth.

However I would like to add another column which stores the time the forecast, something like

```
rid  | rast  | filename      | forecast_date
1      ...     field1.tiff      2012-08-09
2      ...     field10.tiff     2012-08-10
```

Is this possible?

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like ALTER TABLE followed by UPDATE. I mean:

```
ALTER TABLE public.latest ADD COLUMN forecast_date date;

UPDATE TABLE public.latest SET forecast_date = (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps too late for OP, but might help others: why not do it by a batch file? I assume OP's situation and nullable `forecast_date` column:

```
@echo off

setlocal
SET PGPORT=5432
SET PGHOST=localhost
SET PGUSER=postgres
SET PGPASSFILE=*[path_to_your_.pgpass_file][1]*

if "%1"=="" ( 
  set /p %1= "Set path to the image:" 
)

raster2pgsql -a -d tiff/field*.tiff -F %1 public.latest | psql -d my_db

if "%2"=="" ( 
  set /p %2= "Set forecast date:" 
)

psql -d my_db -c "UPDATE public.latest SET forecast_date = %2 WHERE forecast_date IS NULL;"

pause 
endlocal
```

Comments:

- `@echo off` should remove unnecessary noise (printing the code)
- `setlocal` is not mandatory, if you don't need to use more databases through the same command line; it would be very useful if you had set your password there; however, I assume you do it right and store your password in the .pgpass file
- the "if" parts are there to allow you call the script both with and without parameters
- `my_db` is your database
- among `raster2pgsql` parameters, `-a` is important - this way you add to already established database; otherwise, you would have to replace the following SQL statement with the one [jorgeas80](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31282/12768) suggested
- that pgsql statement contains SQL UPDATE. Watch out for badly imported rows, otherwise they would get the same date as the new raster; this could be improved, but I assume that this version suffices
- pause causes the script to wait until you hit any key; useful if you run the script from anywhere but the command line

This is a result of a day or two of trying to solve roughly the same problem as the OP had; I can't confess I really understand command line, batch files, raster2pgsql and psql (I didn't know them at all before I started), so something might be done much better some other way. But this solution works, at least for me.